# Adding icons to text unstable

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I would like do add an icon to the text in one of the slides.
I've tried a few things but the end result is unstable. The icon are being printed in the html file, but If I add a slide or some text the the icons dissapear. Even if I revert what I've done with Ctrl+Z to previous working code the icons don't get printed...

I might be missing something, but the bookdown [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html) didn't have anything on the subject...

````
---
title: 'Title'
author: "Author"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    self_contained: true
    incremental: false
---

```{r knitr_init, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
## Global options
library(knitr)
library(shiny)

opts_chunk$set(
  cache = FALSE,
  prompt = FALSE,
  tidy = FALSE,
  comment = NA,
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE
)

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

```


## S1

`r shiny::tags$i(class = "fa fa-arrow-down",style = "color: rgb(0,166,90)")`
item 3

`r shiny::tags$i(class = "fa fa-arrow-down",style = "color: rgb(0,166,90)")`
item 2


## S2

```{r, echo=F}
data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10) %>%
    plot_ly(x=~a,y=~b)
```
````

Writing the icons as `<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" style="color: rgb(0,166,90)"></i>`  didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the package `icon` (more information [here](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/icon)).

````
---
title: 'Title'
author: "Author"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    self_contained: true
    incremental: false
---

```{r knitr_init, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
## Global options
library(knitr)
library(shiny)

opts_chunk$set(
  cache = FALSE,
  prompt = FALSE,
  tidy = FALSE,
  comment = NA,
  message = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE,
  echo=FALSE
)

library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(icon)
```


## S1

```{r icon-style1}
icon_style(fontawesome("arrow-down", style = "solid"), scale = 2, fill = "#00A65A")
```
item 3

```{r icon-style2}
icon_style(fontawesome("arrow-down", style = "solid"), scale = 2, fill = "#00A65A")
```
item 2


## S2

```{r, echo=F}
data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10) %>%
    plot_ly(x=~a,y=~b)
```
````

-output

[image]

I just added two code chunks, one for each icon. Additionally, in your first `r` chunk, I added `echo=FALSE` to the `opts_chunk$set` and `library(icon)`. In order to achieve the RGB color you chose, the HEX code was needed (#00A65A).